# Drawer Navigation react native paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am extremely new to React and React Native. I need some help regarding nesting a drawer navigator inside the current Stack Navigation.

I have the code on Snack, If someone can please help me i will really appreciate.

https://snack.expo.dev/@smith.james1982/github.com-callstack-react-native-paper-login-template

I want to put the Drawer navigation with Hamburger and Back Arrow using react-native-paper on the Home Screen.

Thanks very much in advance..

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i achieved the solution basically 2 navigations and using a state sharing library use-between. Hopefully it can be helpful to someone

```
import React, { memo, useState } from "react";

import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import { HomeScreen, LoginScreen, RegisterScreen, ForgotPasswordScreen, Dashboard, Demo } from "./screens";

import { useLoginState } from "./core/state";
import { useBetween } from "use-between";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

//Login navigation
const LoginNav = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPasswordScreen" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

//Logged in Navigation
const LoggedInNav = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Demo} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const { loggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = useBetween(useLoginState);
  return loggedIn ? <LoggedInNav /> : <LoginNav />;
}
```